# Increase and Decrease of count

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to create a code that can increase and decrease via clcik of a button
html code but  the problem is i cant get it to function I've tried different options.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="body">
        <h1>COUNTER</h1>
        <span id="time">0</span><br>
        <button id="lower"  onclick="reduceone()" type="button">LOWER COUNT</button><BR>
        <button id="add" onclick="addone()" type="button">ADD COUNT</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code:

```
$("#add").click(function (){
    let count = 0;
    count ++;
    $("#time").text(count);
});

$(#lower).click(function(){
    let count = 0;
    count --;
    $("#time").text(count)
});
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between local and global variables. The scope of `let count = 0;` is only available in that click function. Move it outside and it will be available to both.

Comment: You have to share the `count` variable to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to share the state between two functions so each of them could see the shared state that they are changing.

Also, all id or class names should be between inverted commas like that `"#lower"`

```js
let count = 0; // Shared state that both functions can see

$("#add").click(function (){
    count++;
    $("#time").text(count);
});

$("#lower").click(function(){ // "#lower" not #lower
    count--;
    $("#time").text(count)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   let count = 0;
$("#add").click(function (){
    count ++;
    $("#time").text(count);
});

$(#lower).click(function(){
    count --;
    $("#time").text(count)
});
```

You have to make variable (count ) a global variable so all functions can access his value . If you put variable(count) in a function then only that function can access his value . Hope you understand

Comment: Sorry i forgot o mention that you have mistake at this line ```$(#lower).click(function() ``` change it to ```$("#lower").click(function() ``` .See those commas(" ")